# NodeJS mysql дождаться и вернуть

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, асинхронность

Мыслю php и шарпом... Но ничего не выходит( Вложенных запросов получается слишком много, что путает код. Имеется большая необходимость вынести часто-используемые запросы в отдельные методы с возвратом результата, но не тут то было... Покажите на таком вот примере как сделать:

```
var titles = GetTitles();
///....
function GetTitles() {
var titles;
connection.query('SELECT * FROM titles', function (err, rows) {
    titles = rows;
});
 return titles; //вот тут null возвращает(
}
```

Comment: Привыкайте. Объединяйте запросы. Загуглите promises.

Comment: promises гуглил, они для установки требуют некоторые питон, другие с++ или еще левые зависимости... что для моего проекта не приемлено.... может чистых я просто не нашел, хз(

Comment: а объединять запросы я не могу, у меня после каждого запроса обработка данных, на основе чего формируется следующий запрос и т.д..

Comment: вообще-то это стандартный объект js.. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise и вот вам еще интересное чтиво - http://www.sql.ru/docs/sql/u_sql/ch6.shtml

Comment: как бы там нибыло чистых nmp модулей я не нашел. Если так уверен в своей правоте, то найди чтолибо конкретное и подкрепи примером

Comment: Пример в ответе.

Comment: @beatsspam какие к черту модули? Это стандартные элементы языка. Они без модулей работают.